# Find a file in unix using shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to Unix and i have an assignment, where im struggling to find the solution
Find a given file in given directory and subdirectories recursively
If yes, print the full file path along with its size and word count, last modified time .

I tried using

```
find . -name "*.xlsx"
```

im getting some values
i want to do it in sh program

In shell i tried,

```
#!/bin/sh

file="/home/sample"
if[[$(find . -name "*.xlsx") -gt 0]]
then
echo"files are there"
fi
```

I need to get the values, instead im getting error. How to run the find in if statement.
Thanks

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: you should search some bash tutorial, get to know how to write `if` statement, and how to use `-gt 0`

Comment: I cant even go into the loop, error at then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue was you need to have space between `if` and `[[..` , Also space after `echo` and the string to print. Also add `;` after `]]`
Secondly, use `-n` inside if with find. It will test for a non-empty string. This will make your `if` statement and `find` work.

```
if [[ -n $(find . -name "*.txt") ]];
    then
    echo $PWD/*.txt # This will print full path of file.
     wc  *.txt | awk '{print "Word Count:",$1,"File Size:",$3,"Bytes" }' #Prints word count and size
    fi
```

For getting word count and file size we can use `wc` command. First column gives the word count and third column gives the file size in bytes. You can use `awk` to print the columns.

Comment: Since you are looking for a file, it is better to type the command: find . - type f -name "*.xlsx"

Comment: Just a note, you don't need to put a semi-colon after the double bracket unless you write the "then" on the same line.